# Integral of Sinx with absolute value

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Which one is correct?

in Microsoft Mathematics :

[image]

in Wolfram Alpha :

[image]

and what does $\mathrm{sgn} (\sin x)$ mean ?

Finally, what is the answer to this integral?

Comment: Microsoft doesn't know that you meant the same thing by $X$ as you meant by $x$.

Comment: Note that the input to Microsoft Mathematics has an uppercase $X$ as the argument to the sine, but a lowercase $x$ as the integration variable.

Comment: Alpha's answer is only correct if you consider each interval $n\pi < x < (n+1)\pi$ separately. If you want an antiderivative valid on the whole real line, you must piece together these functions with different constants of integration on each interval, so that you get a single continuous function.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct.

In the first case, the integrand was $\sin X$ (note the uppercase) which is independent of $x$.
In the second case, the integrand was $\sin x$ which is a function of $x$.

$\operatorname{sgn}(x)$ is the sign function:
$$
\operatorname{sgn}(x) =
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
1 &: x > 0, \\
0 &: x = 0,\\
-1 &: x < 0.
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$